# Using standard unicorn_init.sh to boot rails app

Tags: linux, bash, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the standard unicorn_init.sh file sym-linked to my /etc/init.d

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Example init script, this can be used with nginx, too,
# since nginx and unicorn accept the same signals

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=<APP HOME DIRECTORY>
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; $APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
action="$1"
set -u

old_pid="$PID.oldbin"

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
        test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
        test -s $old_pid && kill -$1 `cat $old_pid`
}

case $action in
start)
        sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
        su -c "$CMD" - <USER>
        ;;
stop)
        sig QUIT && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
force-stop)
        sig TERM && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
restart|reload)
        sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
        su -c "$CMD" - <USER>
        ;;
upgrade)
        if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
        then
                n=$TIMEOUT
                while test -s $old_pid && test $n -ge 0
                do
                        printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
                done
                echo

                if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $old_pid
                then
                        echo >&2 "$old_pid still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
                        exit 1
                fi
                exit 0
        fi
        echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
        su -c "$CMD" - <USER>
        ;;
reopen-logs)
        sig USR1
        ;;
*)
        echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Saying

```
service unicorn_<APP NAME> start
```

app boots no problem and browser resolves all requests
but when I try to stop the service

```
service unicorn_<APP NAME> stop
```

I get the error from the file "Not running", I try to restart

```
service  unicorn_<APP_NAME> restart
```

I get the error:

```
Couldn't reload, starting 'cd <APP_NAME>; <APP_NAME>/bin/unicorn -D -c <APP_NAME>/config/unicorn.rb -E production' instead
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

I think it is because it loses track of the pid for the worker processes and checking the /tmp/pid area unicorn.pid does not exist and if I create a blank one it makes no difference.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Dont you have to replace `<APP_HOME_DIRECTORY>` in line 8 by the real installation directory of your app?

Comment: I have the correct directory in there just redacted for posting on here

Comment: Tbh I have no idea about unicorn, however the documentation [here](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/unicorn_1.html) does not mention that a pid-file is written. However for [unicorn_rails](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/unicorn_rails_1.html) this seems to be the case. So maybe you have to use unicorn_rails instead of unicorn?